# Windows Null not Working Correctly

Tags: windows-7, git

GitHub for Windows is not working correctly, citing a `/dev/null` error. I have since discovered that Windows' `null.sys` and `Null` device may have something to do with it, as running `dir > nul` returns an error rather than nothing (like it supposedly should, as it does on installations that work correctly).

This is on Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium (not as many administrative tools, sorry) if it helps.

I have already:

- run `sfc /scannow` (multiple times)
- rebooted (many times)
- stopped and started the Null device in device manager

Even through a lot of Googling, I still haven't found a solution (or anyone else with the problem, for that matter) so I think this might be a special case.

Has anyone seen this before? Did you find a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide the exact error messages you're getting with GitHub for Windows and with `dir >nul`

Comment: GitHub for Windows: "Cannot clone 'repo' - Please check your internet connection" and `dir > nul` "The system cannot find the file specified." I know the internet connection is fine, as the GitHub log has a `/dev/null` error, same as git bash.